# Keep footer at bottom of window regardless of content height

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my website I want the footer to stay at the bottom of the browser window at all times, regardless of the content height.

I tried the numerous stickyfooter examples but all of them put the footer at the bottom of the content if the content is longer than the browser window.

Right now my footer is at the end of the content and below the bottom of the browser window.  I want to move it up to the bottom of the browser window and keep it there at all times.

Comment: Please paste jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will stick your footer to the bottom of the window.

```
footer {  /* Or whatever you use for a footer element.  Use your CSS selector here */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
body {
  padding-bottom: 40px; /* Footer height goes here */
}
```

Comment: Genius!  Thanks heaps for this.  It worked perfectly.